# Permission Denied (public key) in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssh, public-key, openvpn

I am new to Bit Bucket and Visual Studio Code. I gets this error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

On fetch and checkout command. I can't even push or pull codes through VSCode. But I can do it through terminal use.

Please, help with any solutions.

Comment: why are vs2012 and openvpn tagged?

Comment: I am using visual studio and a vpn to also

Comment: Can confirm. Same behaviour for me - also works if I manually use the terminal. I use an encrypted key and github.